# Datetime and GroupBy in LINQPAD 5 with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linqpad

I'm using LINQPAD 5 with a connection to MySQL. Trying to run the following expression:

```
Productions.Where(p => p.Datetime.Year == 2018).GroupBy(p => p.Amount)
```

it results in:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?.datetime)
```

LINQPAD converts the expression into the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT t0.amount, YEAR(A6139838?.datetime) AS c0
FROM productions AS t0
WHERE (YEAR(t0.datetime) = 2018)
GROUP BY t0.amount
```

The problem comes from accessing ".Year",

```
.GroupBy(p => p.Datetime)  //<-- this works
.GroupBy(p => p.Datetime.Year) //<--- MysqlException
```

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: why YEAR(A6139838?.datetime)?

Comment: I don't know. That's how LINQPAD converts my expression

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Method 1:**

```
.GroupBy(p => p.Datetime != null ? (int)p.Datetime.Year : 0)
```

**Method 2:**

Change the property name of Datetime to something else. Actually name is same as the SQL data type. There may be conflicts

Comment: I've tried both methods, renamed Datetime to "dt", still the same. I've reported a bug to the Linqpad-developer